# Design pattern for non-blocking nested function calls in main thread of GUI?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt5, qprocess

I need some help with identifying a design pattern or a technique to make a PyQt GUI application non-blocking, when it has multiple nested calls which invoke one external subprocess after another. The pseudocode is:

```
class MainWindow:
    def executeInSubprocess(self, theCommand):
        subprocess.run(theCommand, check = True)
        #program control reaches here only after the command executed by subprocess.run completes execution
  
    def function1(self):
        commandToExecute = ['python', '-m', 'someProgram.py', '--CLA_option']
        self.executeInSubprocess(commandToExecute)
        self.function2()
        #some commands to update the GUI widgets
    
    def function2(self):
        #Some lines here gather data generated by running function1
        self.function3(data)
  
    def function3(self, data): 
        commandToExecute = ['python', '-m', 'anotherProgram.py', '--CLA_option']
        for oneData in data:
            newCommand = commandToExecute[:] #copy contents of list
            newCommand.append('--someOption')
            newCommand.append(oneData)
            self.executeInSubprocess(newCommand)
```

When the user clicks a button on the GUI, the `function1` gets invoked. The button remains disabled until the `#some commands to update the GUI widgets` line, where the button is re-enabled.

**The problem:**

1. How to design it in such a way that `executeInSubprocess` is non-blocking? I'd like to try replacing `subprocess.run` with `QProcess`, which would not wait until the external command completes, thereby not freezing the GUI.
2. `executeInSubprocess` is called inside a `for` loop multiple times in `function3`, and is dependent on the data generated by `function1`.

These functions are not too large, so it shouldn't be an issue refactoring it. What I need, is knowledge on a good way to design such a scenario. I've considered putting references to `function1`, `function2` and `function3` in a list and having a function in a class call them one by one, but then the `executeInSubprocess` in `function3` complicates things.

Update: I've provided an example of how complex and intertwined the code can get.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: ascii -*-
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QPlainTextEdit, QVBoxLayout, QWidget)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QProcess
from collections import deque
import sys

# Note: The objective was to design a way to execute a function and return control back to the main thread so that the GUI does not freeze.
# But it had to be done in a way that a function could invoke another function, which could invoke another function. Each of these functions
# can have one or more external commands that they need to run. So after invoking each external process, control has to return to the main thread
# and then after running the external process completes, the next command or function needs to run and return control to the main thread and 
# so on until all functions and external commands are exhausted. What's given below is a very crude, tangled design that needs to be improved.

class ExternalProcessInvoker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.externalProcess = None
        self.currentFunction = None
        self.functionQueue = deque() #a sequence of functions to be executed
        self.commandQueue = dict() #{the key is a function reference: the value is a list of commands [['python', 'prog1.py'], ['python', 'prog2.py'], ...]}
        self.FIRST_ELEMENT_OF_LIST = 0
        self.UTF8 = 'utf8'        
        
    def registerTheMessageFunction(self, functionReference):
        self.message = functionReference
    
    def startTheProcess(self):
        while self.functionQueue:
            #print('Elements in queue are: ', self.functionQueue)
            theFunctionToExecute = self.functionQueue.popleft()
            #---run the function
            theFunctionToExecute(theFunctionToExecute) #The function may populate commandQueue when run
            self.currentFunction = theFunctionToExecute
            self.checkForMoreFunctionPopulatedCommandsToExecute()

    def checkForMoreFunctionPopulatedCommandsToExecute(self):
        #---check if commandQueue is populated with any external process that needs to be run    
        if self.currentFunction in self.commandQueue:
            if self.commandQueue[self.currentFunction]:#contains some command
                command = self.commandQueue[self.currentFunction].popleft()
                #command = self.convertToUTF8(command)
                if self.externalProcess is None:  # No process running.
                    #---run the command
                    self.message('Executing ' + str(command)); print('Executing ', command)
                    self.externalProcess = QProcess() 
                    self.externalProcess.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.functionForStdout)
                    self.externalProcess.readyReadStandardError.connect(self.functionForStderr)
                    self.externalProcess.stateChanged.connect(self.functionForStateChange)
                    self.externalProcess.finished.connect(self.processCompleted)  # Clean up once complete.
                    self.externalProcess.start(command[self.FIRST_ELEMENT_OF_LIST], command[self.FIRST_ELEMENT_OF_LIST:]) #the first argument is the first command element (usually 'python'). The second argument is a list of all the remaining elements of the command
                    print('Process ID: ', self.externalProcess.processId())    
        else:
            self.currentFunction = None              
    
    def convertToUTF8(self, command):
        return [oneString.encode('utf-8') for oneString in command]

    def stopTheProcess(self):
        self.message('Attempting to stop the processes')
        if self.externalProcess:
            self.externalProcess.kill()
        self.message('Also cleared ' + len(self.functionQueue) + ' items from execution queue')
        self.functionQueue.clear()

    def functionForStderr(self):
        data = self.externalProcess.readAllStandardError()
        stderr = bytes(data).decode(self.UTF8)
        self.message(stderr)

    def functionForStdout(self):
        data = self.externalProcess.readAllStandardOutput()
        stdout = bytes(data).decode(self.UTF8)
        self.message(stdout)

    def functionForStateChange(self, state):
        states = {QProcess.NotRunning: 'Not running', QProcess.Starting: 'Starting', QProcess.Running: 'Running'}
        state_name = states[state]
        self.message(f'State changed: {state_name}')

    def processCompleted(self):
        self.message('Process finished.')
        self.externalProcess = None
        self.checkForMoreFunctionPopulatedCommandsToExecute()

    def addThisFunctionToProcessingQueue(self, functionReference):
        #print('Received request to add this function to processing queue: ', functionReference)
        #print('What's already in processing queue: ', self.functionQueue)
        self.functionQueue.append(functionReference)

    def addThisCommandToProcessingList(self, command, functionReference):
        if functionReference not in self.commandQueue:
            self.commandQueue[functionReference] = deque()
        self.commandQueue[functionReference].append(command)
        #print('\nfunc ref: ', functionReference, ' command: ', command)
        self.message('Added ' + str(command) + ' for processing')
        #print(self.commandQueue)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.proc = ExternalProcessInvoker()
        self.proc.registerTheMessageFunction(self.message)

        self.executeButton = QPushButton('Execute') #TODO: Disable button until processing completes or processes are killed
        self.executeButton.pressed.connect(self.initiateProcessing)
        self.killButton = QPushButton('Kill process') #TODO: Disable button until processing is started
        self.killButton.pressed.connect(self.killProcessing)        
        self.textDisplay = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.textDisplay.setReadOnly(True)

        boxLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        boxLayout.addWidget(self.executeButton)
        boxLayout.addWidget(self.killButton)
        boxLayout.addWidget(self.textDisplay)

        theWidget = QWidget()
        theWidget.setLayout(boxLayout)

        self.setCentralWidget(theWidget)
        
    def message(self, mssg):
        self.textDisplay.appendPlainText(mssg)
        
    def initiateProcessing(self):
        print('Processing initiated')
        #---first populate the functions and commands to execute
        self.proc.addThisFunctionToProcessingQueue(self.function1)
        self.proc.addThisFunctionToProcessingQueue(self.function2)
        self.proc.addThisFunctionToProcessingQueue(self.function3)
        self.proc.startTheProcess()
        
    def function1(self, functionReference):
        self.message('Executing function1')
        command = ['python', 'dummyScript1.py']
        self.proc.addThisCommandToProcessingList(command, functionReference)
        
    def function2(self, functionReference):
        self.message('Executing function2')
        
    def function3(self, functionReference):
        self.message('Executing function3')
        maxInvocations = 5
        secondsToSleep = 1
        for _ in range(maxInvocations):
            command = ['python', 'dummyScript2.py', str(secondsToSleep)]
            self.proc.addThisCommandToProcessingList(command, functionReference) 
            secondsToSleep = secondsToSleep + 1

        self.message('Processing complete')
        print('Completed')
    
    def killProcessing(self):
        self.proc.stopTheProcess()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

Dummy script 1:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: ascii -*-
import time
import datetime

sec = 3
print(datetime.datetime.now(), " Going to sleep for ", sec, " seconds")
time.sleep(sec)
print(datetime.datetime.now(), " Done sleeping dummy script1")
```

Dummy script 2:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: ascii -*-
import time

def gotosleep(sleepTime):
    print("Going to sleep for ", sleepTime, " seconds")
    time.sleep(sleepTime)
    print("Done sleeping for ", sleepTime, " seconds in dummy script2")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    FIRST_EXTRA_ARG = 1
    sleepTime = sys.argv[FIRST_EXTRA_ARG]
    gotosleep(sleepTime)
```

Comment: You can use `QThread` and `signal slot` to transfer data to gui from thread

Comment: It's not about how to transfer data. It's about how to invoke an external process from a function, return control to the GUI main thread, then when the external process completes, automatically call another function which invokes another external process and so on...until there are no more functions and external processes to invoke. The user clicks the button on the GUI only once, to start this cascading processing. The objective is also that the GUI shouldn't freeze when all this processing is going on.

Comment: Use [QProcess](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html)

Comment: @Nav What exactly is your question? You already know about `QProcess`, so presumably you've also read the Qt documentation. All you need is a simple chain of signals and slots to achieve what you want. Asking for "good/best" ways to do this seems largely opinion-based if all you provide is pseudo-code.

Comment: @ekhumoro: I don't see how using signals or slots will work here. I'm already trying to use `QProcess` in a separate class to invoke the external command. Please read the question and my comments above. I've explained exactly what I'm asking for. Since the external processes are long-running, I need a way to return control back to the main thread and also to ensure that each function and the commands in them are executed one by one. If you just follow the code flow, you'll understand why it's difficult. If it's achievable by signals and slots, please show me how.

Comment: @Nav There's nothing in either your question or your comments that explains why you're unable to use `QProcess`. Thus, it's unclear whether you understand that `QProcess` provides both synchronous and asynchronus APIs, which require different handling (see, for eample, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49979592/984421)). Please therefore provide a [mre].

Comment: Just because you've seen others on this community ask for a minimal reproducible example, it does not mean you have to ask for one. Especially in this case, where the design I'm asking about is clear. Anyway, in the process of trying to find a solution, I've written some code that naturally got messed up, but the while loop shows how it is difficult to give control back to the main thread. This needs a more elegant design pattern.

Comment: Did you get the answer you needed outside this thread? I wont spend time explaining if you have.

Comment: @ChumbiChubaGo: That was a long time ago. I'm no longer working on that project, so I do not need an explanation, but it will surely help others if you answer it. Thanks for offering to help.