# Using QProcess and writing result to file

Tags: c++, qt5, qprocess

I need to write a program that will call a process and a command in it, and put the result in a separate file, I wrote the program itself, but it gives an error: "Error. Using the "path" construction:the template "with the /R parameter is unacceptable.". The trick is that the command works in cmd and does not issue any errors, and if I call the command via QProcess, then there is always an error. I'm using Qt5.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QString>
 
void getPathToFile(QString fileName);
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
 
    QProcess splitter;
    QString fileName = "Bones";
    getPathToFile(fileName);
 
    return a.exec();
}
 
void getPathToFile(QString fileName)
{
    QString command = "where /r C:\\Qt\\Qt_Apps " + fileName + ".mpg > C:\\Qt\\Qt_Apps\\resultFind.txt";
    QProcess finder;
    finder.startDetached(command);
}
```

Comment: Instead of starting another process with a Windows command which is error-prone, you might investigate into [QDir](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdir.html).

Comment: I'd suspect the redirection and try getting the output from the `QProcess` object, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49976741/get-output-in-qt-qprocessstart-and-qprocessreadallstandardoutput

Comment: You cannot provide just your complete command line in the first parameter of [QProcess::startDetached](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qprocess.html#startDetached-1). The have to be passed as list (i.e. as separate strings) in the 2nd parameter `arguments`.

Comment: Btw. please note that [QProcess::startDetached()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qprocess.html#startDetached-1) is a static function. It's intended to be called like e.g. `QProcess::startDetached(command);`, i.e. no instance of `QProcess` is needed.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Actually, the `static` version is an overload of the non-static [`startDetached()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qprocess.html#startDetached) so it's not necessarily intended to by used through the `static` overload :)